# Using accessors in Spring Boot JavaBean properties binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using `@ConfigurationProperties` to bind properties to a java bean in a spring boot project like so: (example taken from spring docs)

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private boolean enabled;

    private InetAddress remoteAddress;

    private final Security security = new Security();

    public boolean isEnabled() { ... }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) { ... }

    public InetAddress getRemoteAddress() { ... }

    public void setRemoteAddress(InetAddress remoteAddress) { ... }
```

But in the [Spring Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-java-bean-binding) there is a warning that

> The properties that map to @ConfigurationProperties classes available in Spring Boot, which are configured via properties files, YAML files, environment variables etc., are public API but the accessors (getters/setters) of the class itself are not meant to be used directly.

I'm a little puzzled as to what this means. Is this saying I should make the instance fields `public` and not use the getters in the `AcmeProperties` bean (ie. `getRemoteAddress()`)? I don't understand why accessing the fields directly vs. through getters would make a difference. And plenty of [tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) have those fields as `private`.

Or is this warning referring to something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't be using the setters only the getters, but the setters are required for binding to work (as it needs a writeable property). Making the field public won't help (a field isn't a property in the sense of the Java Beans Specification). I think the statement is confusing and not really clarifying things.

Comment: @M.Deinum So that warning is only for the setters but **not** the getters? It specifically mentions `getters` though...

Comment: Yeah I know, but I suspect it is for setters only as those are needed for binding to work. The getters you need to get the values out, so not using the getters isn't an option as that would also defy the use of typesafe configuration classes wouldn't it.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, that's what's confusing me. Not sure how you would use this without the getters besides for making the fields public which violates the Bean spec. Unless the warning is going on something else.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation specifically refers to internal Spring Boot classes that are annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. I agree that the documentation is confusing, but you can see the intent of this documentation from the following Spring Boot GitHub Issue comments:

> - Regardless of the issue, please do not extend from our `@ConfigurationProperties`, *especially* with the same prefix.
> - The annotation processor needs to have the source code to be able to extract things like default value and documentation. By extending a class that's outside of your compilation context, you won't get a consistent set of metadata (worse they'd be duplicated in your example).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10713#issuecomment-338193282

> > I was just wondering whether extending the official @ConfigurationProperties is a valid use case.
>
> It is not (that or any other `@ConfigurationProperties` bean actually). Let me clarify that in the documentation.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10713#issuecomment-338198921

> We've documented that `@ConfigurationProperties` are not public API in [#16704](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16704) so that includes extending from them. Looking at the current doc, I don't feel adding something more explicit is warranted.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10713#issuecomment-533154033

GitHub issue [#16704](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16704) led to commit [47a9bb1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/47a9bb1c0e3d5758bc5358f2953d93f1412748db) that added this documentation.

In conclusion, it's fine to use getters/setters of your custom `@ConfigurationProperties` classes.